# Finish multiple activities on an authentication flow android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

So I have an app that has authentication on it
here is the flow:

LoginPage -> Register -> RegisterConfirmation -> OTP Code -> EmailVerification -> Homepage

I want that if the user is already on OTP Code or Email Verification and he pressed the back button, the user will get straight to Homepage because he already got the AccessToken since RegisterConfirmation.

Here's the flow I want to look like:
[image: flow]

How can I possible does this, I've already done some research but all I got is only how to finish only one activity (parent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let the user go to OTP Code and check in  registerconfirmation activity if the user already obtained his token access.

If you try to start an activity say A and you are in the current activity say D, you can use this with your intent :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
```

To clear top activities (B,C,D)

EDIT:

You can keep the current instance of your activity using

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: thanks sir, i tried this one but what this also finish the activity A. But what I want is that from activity D, it go back to activity A instead of startactivity A

Comment: Okay you can achieve this using intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Answer (score 0):

When the user presses Back button do the below on `onBackPressed()` method. This might solve your problem. What it does is it clears the previous task and creates a new task
with the only activity in stack.

```
val intent = Intent(this,HomeActivity::class.java).apply{
addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
}
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

Comment: does this have any differences with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ?

Comment: Best to my understanding, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` clears all the activities on top of the intent activity